# Convert string to datetime and change GMT in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

i have a problems to convert and change the GMT, please i triyng with this `new Date(date)` [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/16ehj22d/), and i think this work, but i want change the format like this **YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss**, but the result show "invalid format date", and i cant use the `format` function. Please help me

Comment: Did the solution below work out for you?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript will not accept the date/time format you are passing to it. Convert the timestamp first, then pass the array values like this:

```
var t = "2015-06-23 21:07:33".split(/[- :]/);
var targetTime = new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);
```

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/16ehj22d/2/